# How to understand the usage of extern when sharing variable between multiple files?

Tags: c++, extern

Let's say I have three files, `f1.h`,`f2.h`,and `common.cc`.

In `f1.h`, `extern std::vector<void*> buffer;` is declared.

In `f2.h`, `extern std::vector<void*> buffer;` is also declared.

In `common.cc`, `std::vector<void*> buffer;` is defined.

I will create two separate thread, which include `f1.h` and `f2.h`, respectively.
Can I modify this `buffer` on each thread individually? Since they are shared? Let's forget the lock issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (probably).

I am assuming that the implementation code for the first thread includes `f1.h`, and the implementation for the second thread includes `f2.h`. In this scenario, there will be one instance of `buffer` variable that is visible and accessible in the definition of both threads.

It is perfectly legal to declare the same variable in several files. But for maintainability of code, I would highly recommend against doing it. Prefer declaring shared variables and functions in a single header file included in all the `.cpp` files that needs its definition. Otherwise it is very easy in a later refactor to change the signature in one place and not in the other. This is a very confusing situation, where typically all source files might compile but you have a link error because mangling of both declarations don't match.

You have mentioned it in the question, but I just want to stress a bit that accessing a STL collection like `std::vector` in several threads requires a mutex at each read or write access, unless both threads are exclusively performing read access. And of course the mutex *has* to be shared between threads also. If threads were locking different mutex, there would be strictly no protection at all.